# How can I iterate over java Iterable using RichFaces 'repeat' tag?

Tags: java, jsf, iterator, richfaces

In Java, I'm able to use for-loops to iterate over ArrayLists or Iterables.  In RichFaces, I can use the facelet "repeat" tag to iterate over ArrayLists, but not Iterables.  The error messages I get from using an Iterable are that the attributes or methods of the items in the Iterable cannot be found.  How should I code an Iterable so that RichFaces sees the items in it as their proper class, just as Java itself does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on `org.richfaces.component.UISequence#createFacesModel` valid types for value attribute of a4j:repeat (and other RichFaces data iteration components (rich:list, rich:dataTable, etc.)) are the following:

```
javax.faces.model.DataModel
java.util.List
java.lang.Object[]
java.sql.ResultSet
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result
```

So, in your case iterables should implement `java.util.List` interface.

Comment: You're right that when I implement the `List` interface, RichFaces can now iterate over my data structure.  However, it does it from the first element to the last, in order.  I wrote an `iterator()` method for the `Iterable` to go through the list in a special, rule-based order.  When using the `List` interface, RichFaces doesn't even attempt to use `iterator()`.  Do you have any suggestions for how to make RichFaces use the iterator?

Comment: I ended up changing my data structure implementation a lot.  The class now implements the List interface for use with RichFaces and Iterable for use with Java.  I moved the rule-based logic from the iterator method into the class constructor, which saves the ordered items for later use.  That may give a bit of a performance boost, too.